# Does AWS PHP SDK automatically retry multipart uploads?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

Based on the sdk code, the [s3 client code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/f4b153edca8cea320afafc08a53a733efa7e4366/src/S3/S3Client.php#L15) uses retry logic, but the sample code from [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/s3-multipart-upload.html) suggest doing a loop until the multipart upload finishes correctly.

```html
$s3Client = new S3Client([
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region' => 'us-east-2',
    'version' => '2006-03-01'
]);

$bucket = 'your-bucket';
$key = 'my-file.zip';

// Using stream instead of file path
$source = fopen('/path/to/large/file.zip', 'rb');

$uploader = new ObjectUploader(
    $s3Client,
    $bucket,
    $key,
    $source
);

do {
    try {
        $result = $uploader->upload();
        if ($result["@metadata"]["statusCode"] == '200') {
            print('<p>File successfully uploaded to ' . $result["ObjectURL"] . '.</p>');
        }
        print($result);
    } catch (MultipartUploadException $e) {
        rewind($source);
        $uploader = new MultipartUploader($s3Client, $source, [
            'state' => $e->getState(),
        ]);
    }
} while (!isset($result));
```

Is that MultipartUploadException being thrown after the standard 3 retries for it have happened? Or are multipart uploads not covered by the retry policy?

Comment: I'm going to guess that retry middleware is for API rate limiting. Work-arounds for rate limiting littered everyone's AWS code until they started adding the functionality into the sdk

Comment: From [the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-php/v3/developer-guide/faq.html#how-is-retry-scheme-handled-in-the-sdk-php):  

The AWS SDK for PHP haas a RetryMiddleware that handles retry behavior. In terms of 5xx HTTP status codes for server errors, the SDK retries on 500, 502, 503 and 504.  

Throttling exceptions, including RequestLimitExceeded, Throttling, ProvisionedThroughputExceededException, ThrottlingException, RequestThrottled and BandwidthLimitExceeded, are also handled with retries.